# Eclipse 3.6 Helios for Ubuntu 10.10

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, open-source, ubuntu

I have ubuntu 10.10 net book edition installed on my dell studio laptop. I downloaded helios for the eclipse site but when I am not able to run it. I have downloaded eclipse 3.5 from synaptic package manager but I am not able to update eclipse 3.5 to eclipse 3.6. Is der any other way to have updated eclipse? Eclipse 3.6 supports HTML 5.

Please let me know, thanks a lot in advance

Comment: You are "not able to run it"... this is not very precise.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try this:

To install eclipse on ubuntu you need to download it first from http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/
Extract the downloaded file by right click on it and extract here or running the following:

```
tar xzf dir/eclipse-SDK-3.3.1.1-linux-gtk.tar.gz
```

Where eclipse-SDK-3.3.1.1-linux-gtk is your eclipse-SDK name with version and dir is the directory of eclipse-sdk.

Now move it to the root directory. Apply the following command to do this.

```
sudo mv dir/eclipse ~
```

Now you are ready to configure your eclipse. To do this follow the following step by step...

```
sudo mv eclipse /opt/
```

Take care of the permissions:

```
sudo chmod -R +r /opt/eclipse
sudo chmod +x /opt/eclipse/eclipse
```

Create an executable in your path:

```
sudo touch /usr/bin/eclipse
sudo chmod 755 /usr/bin/eclipse
sudo gedit /usr/bin/eclipse
```

Copy the following content and save the file:

```
#!/bin/sh
export ECLIPSE_HOME="/opt/eclipse"
$ECLIPSE_HOME/eclipse $*
```

Let’s also make eclipse executable everywhere by creating a symlink:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/eclipse /bin/eclipse
```

Create the menu icon:

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/applications/eclipse.desktop
```

Type in this content and save:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Eclipse
Comment=Eclipse IDE
Exec=eclipse
Icon=/opt/eclipse/icon.xpm
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=GNOME;Application;Development;
StartupNotify=true
```

Run for the first time:

```
eclipse -clean
```

You can now start Eclipse by simply typing eclipse in the terminal or from the GNOME menu Applications -> Programming -> Eclipse

Comment: where do you paste the content, in which files or in which directories?

Comment: Worked fine on Ubuntu 10.10 with a previous version of Eclipse already installed. You just saved my life.

Answer (score 3):

At least, you still have the [manual install](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=10328705#3), which leaves your current Eclipse3.5 untouched (allowing you to go back to it if 3.6 gives you too much troubles)

> To get your 3.6 download running:
>
> - Unzip the download into a directory you have complete control of, usually a directory under your username, preserving folders.
> - Create a shortcut to the eclipse executable, usually in the resulting "`eclipse`" folder.
> - Run the program using the resulting shortcut.
> - When your new eclipse install starts, point to your existing workspace.
>     You can continue with both 3.5 and 3.6 installed using the same workspace, or you can remove 3.5 by deselecting it from your software management program (one of several ways).

[Alexander Pogrebnyak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/185722/alexander-pogrebnyak) actually points out in the comment:

> workspace cannot round trip `3.5->3.6->3.5`.
>   The usual solution is to keep 3.5 and 3.6 versions of workspace in different directories.

The idea to have one workspace for each version is always the safest route to take, with [each of your project imported into each respective workspace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2266993/how-to-import-existing-project-into-workplace-in-eclipse).

---

Note, you have to make sure [your java is correctly installed](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=10226105#4) (which should be already good for you, but just in case):

> Installing Helios 3.6 on Ubuntu 10.10 is rather simple.
>   Download eclipse package from eclipse.org and extract it to a folder in your home directory.
>
> The tricky part is setting up `java6-jdk` from the sun partner repository but there is a [easy to follow guide](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/09/how-to-install-java-jre-and-java-plugin.html):
>   basically you have to enable the partner repository, then install java6 jdk with:

```
sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jre sun-java6-plugin
```

> and then if necessary update your java alternatives with:

```
# shows a list with available java alternatives:
sudo update-java-alternatives -l

# sets the alternative
sudo update-java-alternatives -s java-6-sun
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

Comment: On your last topic, you've probably meant same **PROJECT**, not same **WORKSPACE**, as workspace cannot round trip 3.5->3.6->3.5.  The usual solution is to keep 3.5 and 3.6 versions of workspace in different directories.

Comment: @Alexander: true. I have included your comment in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

The Eclipse version available through the official Ubuntu channels is 3.5 and should *not* be manually upgraded to 3.6.  You probably will not have write permission to do so.

If you must have 3.6 the easiest way is to download the official distribution from eclipse.org, unzip it and run the eclipse binary directly.  This also allows you to fully administer it by yourself with upgrades and extra modules.

Answer (score 2):

The Eclipse version available through the official Ubuntu channels is 3.5 and should not be manually upgraded to 3.6. You probably will not have write permission to do so.

Comment: Wonder if what happened was that _this_ exact question was found when searching on Google and the accepted answer was cut-and-pasted?

Answer (score 2):

There is [a PPA](https://launchpad.net/~eclipse-team/+archive/debian-package) available, that should let you upgrade through package management before the packages reach the Ubuntu repos. Sadly, the packages [seem](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1520424#9) [broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680250/how-to-upgrade-eclipse-from-3-5-galileo-to-3-6-helios-the-proper-way) [right](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/eclipse/+bug/886088) now.

Comment: Just to update - the new 3.7 (Indigo) release seems to work fine in Oneiric.