# Installing Eclipse/Java on Ubuntu

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, ubuntu

I'd like to install Eclipse on Ubuntu for Java development. I'm happy to trade having the newest version for steady updates via package management.

I've done the usual `sudo apt-get install eclipse eclipse-jdt` (java-7-openjdk-i386 is installed and working)

However, when I start Eclipse, there seems to be almost nothing available - no Java editing (not even 'Installed JREs' is present under Window/Preferences). I've tried adding various update sites, installing Marketplace client, WTP, Java EE etc. but just can't get a working install. Oddly, I have it running fine on another machine I set up about a year ago (with the help of [How do I install Eclipse Marketplace in Eclipse Classic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5285623/how-do-i-install-eclipse-marketplace-in-eclipse-classic))

I've given up and reverted to a manual install (along the lines of [Eclipse 3.6 Helios for Ubuntu 10.10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4767584/eclipse-3-6-helios-for-ubuntu-10-10)) but wanted to ask:

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Just for reinforcement, I've been doing Java development on Ubuntu for ~5 years now, and in all that time, I've always manually installed all my tools rather than try to fight the OS on having multiple versions of things installed and in use, sometimes simultaneously.

Comment: You will not get the newest eclipse by using package-management. You should install it by hand. Also I recommend to switch from openjdk to the oracle-jdk (better performance)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I strongly recommend you not to install Eclipse in that way, it is not really useful and you will get just the Eclipse with the Java Standard Perspective. What I recommend you is to download the tar.gz file from the page (including the Java EE perspective). Copy the tar file in a directory where you want all your development tools, like /home/user/dev/eclipse and start from there. You can create a launcher in your desktop to get a faster access to the IDE. When I started with Ubuntu, I used to install the way you had installed (sudo apt-get...) but I can tell you that the best way to do is to install it manually. If the JDK is well installed, you will not have any problem launching your Eclipse. Best regards.

Comment: As a plus, I can tell you that if you want a version of Eclipse, do not install de JUNO since it has some issues and it also consumes more memory than previous versions, install the Indigo or Helios
tar -zxvf eclipse-jee-helios-linux-gtk.tar.gz
If you want also to add it as an item in your menu:
Right click in Applications/Edit Menus
Go to your prefered section (usually programming)
New Item / Browse to /opt/eclipse/eclipse (if you installed it there)

Comment: I work with **JUNO** at my job and have no problems [OS: Ubuntu]. It may use more memory, but not as much more that I have noticed it while my work.

Comment: To add to this, we've had mixed results with Juno at work. Generally positive, but there seemed to be a significant issue with switching between XML editors. There was a patch for it, which now seems to have gone, so I'd guess it's been integrated into the build/standard updates. It now seems to be working fine.

Comment: Many thanks. I'm accepting this answer as confirmation that Ubuntu package management can't deliver a workable Eclipse installation at the moment (without requiring significant effort, detailed understanding and a "healthy" interest in internal workings). Perhaps the eclipse-jdt package will be updated (or an eclipse-jee package created).

Comment: For completeness, here is the Juno patch: http://wiki.eclipse.org/Platform_UI/Juno_Performance_Investigation